# Не получается менять стили блоков при нажатии на кнопку

Tags: reactjs, typescript

я пытаюсь менять стиль блока при нажатии на кнопку при помощи switch и count, если допустим count будет 1 то в состояние записывается класс со стилями, если я нажал еще раз на кнопку то записывается 2 стиль в состояние и т.д

```
let count: number = 0

function changeColor() {
    count++
    if (count == 4) {
        count = 0
    }
    
    switch (count) {
        case 1:
            setStyleBoxColor('ItemBoxStyle1')
            break;
        case 2: 
            setStyleBoxColor('ItemBoxStyle2')
            break;
    }
    console.log(count);
}
```

but in the end i get this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5TmLt.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вынесите `count` в [useState](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html). Если вы используете `let` в теле функционального компонента, на каждый рендеринг будет создана новая переменная